# Php nothing happens when I click login, just removes both fields

Tags: php

Whenever I click the login button both fields just get removed and it stays on the same page which is the login page.  I'm new to php and have tried some other things and watching different videos but I can't seem to fix the problem any help would be appreciated.

After the user has logged in I want them to be redirected to their profile page I have put this in the location header however I can't even get to this point.

login php page

```
    <?php 
session_start();

require"connect.php";

include"navbar.html"; 
?>

<?php  


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


// Assigning POST values to variables.
$username = $_POST['StudentID'];
$password = $_POST['StudentPassword'];

// CHECK FOR THE RECORD FROM TABLE
$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_login` WHERE Student_ID='$username' and Password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){

    header('location: profile.php');

}else{
    echo "Incorrect username or password";

}

}




?>


<head>

<style>

.container{ 
    width: 400px;
    height: 240px;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto; 

}

</style>



</head>


<body>

<div class="container">

<center>
<h3>Student Login</h3>

<form id="login-form" method="post" action="Student_Login.php" >
        <table border="0.5" >
            <tr>
                <td><label for="StudentID">Student ID</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="StudentID" id="StudentID"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="StudentPassword">Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="StudentPassword" id="StudentPassword"></input></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" />


            </tr>
        </table>

</form>

</center>

</div>

</body>
```

connect page

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'recordkeepingsystem');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));



}


?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit'])){` you're not posting anything called `submit`. Have you tried debugging the code? or if you don't have a php debugger installed, try printing something inside the if statement if it's entering there.

Comment: You can use $_SESSION for Login functionality, & use:
 header("Location: http://www.example.com/") to redirect it, you can also redirect page through javascript.

Comment: This type of article posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084481/php-login-and-get-user-information?rq=1

Comment: hi I am submitting the form when the user clicks the login button

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
<?php  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // your logic
}
?>
```

and change your form action `action="Student_Login.php"` to `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"`

Comment: try this $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] cause you are submitting the form on the same page.